# Shifting to next screen from Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery

Tags: tabs, window, titanium, titanium-mobile, photo-gallery

I am using titanium to make a small app where i can click on a 'gallery' button located in a window and it opens photogallery. On selecting the photo it should move to next window. But what it does is, it closes the photogallery first, after that i can see my first(button) screen and then it opens the next window.

I dont want it to show the previous window. Is there a way to do it??

I am adding windows to tabs . Below is my code .

```
cameraButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            chooseImageFromGallery();
        }); 



function chooseImageFromGallery(){

        var capturedImg;

        //TODO     Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
            success : function(event) {

                capturedImg = event.media;

                /* Condition to check the selected media */
                if (event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
                        var window1 = MyWindows.init(capturedImg, docImgModel, previous_win);

                                MyCommon.addWindowToTabGroup(window1);
                        win.close();
                }
            },
            cancel : function() {
                //While cancellation of the process
                activityInd.hide();
                        win.remove(activityInd);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                /* called when there's an error */
                var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                    titleid : 'camera'
                });
                if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                    a.setMessage(L('camera_not_available'));
                } else {
                    a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.message);
                }
                a.show();
                activityInd.hide();
                win.remove(activityInd);

            }
        });

    }
```

The init method just creates a new window and returns it .

The addWindowToTabGroup method adds it to the current tab

```
addWindowToTabGroup(window){
    // tabGroup is a tab at global level declared in app.js
    // activeTab returns the current tab
    tabGroup.activeTab.open(window, {
                animated : true
            });
}
```

Thanks a lot ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:
1- on button click fire a global event which will open your photo gallery and then close your current window.

2- Now in success call back of photo gallery (when photo is selected) write you code of opening the new window you want to show your user ...